# Passing more than 255 characters in a Memo field to Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have an Word Document setup to pull information for existing customers from a database and fill out fields in the document.

All fields successfully pull from the database; however, if the value and any of my memo fields is greater than 255 characters nothing is filled in the document field. I pull data from 44 fields in successfully, the only issue is with the 5 memo fields. If any are above 255 they remain blank but all the other fields still correctly populate.

I have looked for others who have had similar complaints but have not yet discovered how to correct this issue. Most other sites with similar issues point to http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

None of the suggestions or workarounds in that fit my issue.

My Memo field is not formatted in the database and the fields in my document allow an unlimited length.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if we had the code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I finally ended up finding the answer I needed in another SO thread.

```
ActiveDocument.Unprotect
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Text1").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Str1
ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True
```

I had to unprotect the document because it was causing an error if the text were > 255

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make the first field in the record-set being queried has over 255 characters. Make a dummy record to make sure it's the first record in the list.

See --> [here](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks)

Seems like since office 2010 it's been a non-issue. Can't confirm this though.

If that doesn't work, I suppose you could split your 1 memo field into multiple text fields. Not ideal, but it should work.

Ryan

Comment: I have the memo field first, although it isn't always above 255. I'll try the method in your link and see if it works any better. I also am on Office 2007 because that is what our company uses so hopefully the solution can work in the older versions as well